# Permutations & Functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, permutations

This is an assignment question I received a week ago.

A function $f:\{1, 2, \dots ,n\} \to \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ which is a bijection is also called a *permutation*. Let $P_n$ be the set of all permutations on $\{1, 2, \dots , n\}$. Define the relation $\sim$ on $P_n$ by $f\sim g$  iff there exists a permutation $h$ such that $f = h \circ g \circ h^{-1}$.

a) Need to show that it is an equivalence relation.

My Approach:

For a relation to be an equivalence relation, it must be reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

Reflexive:

Let $f \sim f \Longleftrightarrow$ there exists $h$ such that $f = h \circ f \circ h^{-1}$.

My question (this may be silly) but is $h \circ f \circ h^{-1} = f$? I claimed that it was, and thus if $h \circ f \circ h^{-1} = f$, then it is reflexive.

Symmetric:

Let $f \sim g \Longleftrightarrow$ there exists $h$ such that $f = h \circ g \circ h^{-1}$.
Let $g \sim f \Longleftrightarrow$ there exists $h_2$ (may be a different $h$) such that $g = h \circ f \circ h^{-1}$.

If $f = h \circ g \circ h^{-1}$ then
   $f = g$.

And since $g = h \circ f \circ h^{-1}$ then
    $g = f$.

Clearly this is reflexive.

I would like to know if I am in the right direction.

Regards,

Julian.

Answer (score 3):

You are generally going in the right direction.  For reflexive, the permutations do not commute, so $h \circ f \circ h^{-1}$ does not necessarily equal $f$.  But can find a specific $h$ that works.  For symmetric, when you write $g$ you should write $g = h_2 \circ f \circ h_2^{-1}$.  Again, because the permutations do not commute you cannot conclude (and it is not generally true) that $f=g$.  But given $f = h \circ g \circ h^{-1}$ you should be able to find an $h_2$.  For transitive, you assume $f = h \circ g \circ h^{-1}$ and $g= h_2 \circ k \circ h_2^{-1}$  Now can you find $h_3$ such that $f = h_3 \circ k \circ h_3^{-1}$?

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, Ross.

Comment: If h is the identity function, then would h∘f∘h−1 = f since h: A -> A would be the same as it's inverse?

Would that be a specific h that works? Or would it be a different case?

Comment: @JulianPark:  That is exactly what I was thinking.  You have shown $f \sim f$ as you wanted.  Another that works is $f$ itself, as does $f^{-1}$ (which need not be distinct from $f$)